# What would (or do) you call komatsuna in English?

Tags: vegetables, language

What if anything are these greens called in English?

[image]

Likely brassica rapa perviridis.

Comment: The first sentence of that article is *Komatsuna (小松菜コマツナ) or Japanese mustard spinach (Brassica rapa var. perviridis) is a leaf vegetable. =* -- why is that not the answer you seek?

Comment: Hi Kate!  (1) Wikipedia is endlessly wrong (2) There are numerous almost identical questions on here (ie, about other "foreign" so to speak vegetables) and typically the detailed, fine answers (you can't get anywhere else) includes regional variations, UK v. US etc. (I would say in 2023 one shouldn't have to say "Wikipedia is endlessly wrong and that's why I'm asking" - heh!)  But sure I'll edit it for you

Comment: I've seen and eaten a vegetable that looks like that from Chinese grocery stores. The name is just the pinyin of the Chinese name (which I unfortunately don't recall). I'm not sure whether it is the exact same vegetable though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does not have a specific name in English, for the simple reason that it's not traditionally grown outside Asia.

If you find it labelled in English, it will be alternately "spinach", "mustard greens", "Japanese mustard spinach", or even "Japanese turnip greens", none of which are particularly accurate.  Occasionally it gets mislabelled as "pak choi" here on the West Coast, as pak choi is a popular and closely related vegetable.

If a store is being accurate, it will be labelled "komatsuna".

Comment: Amazing info !!!  I think I have indeed seenit mislabelled as "pak choi", as you say.

Comment: If that works for you as an answer, please select it.

Comment: ?  It's usual to way a couple days to be polite to others, even if an answer is outstanding.